# How to fix “Cannot invoke initializer for type 'MKMapRect' with an argument list of type '(MKMapRect)''” error in Swift 5.0

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mapkit

I am using Apple’s [Footprint: Indoor Positioning with Core Location sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/footprint/Introduction/Intro.html) to build a mobile application. This code is in Swift 3.0, and I am converting it to Swift 5.0 syntax. 
When I run this Swift 3.0 code,

```
 var corners =  [MKMapPoint(x: MKMapRectGetMaxX(MKMapRect.world), y: MKMapRectGetMaxY(MKMapRect.world))]
    return HideBackgroundOverlay(points: &corners, count: corners.count)
```

I get this error.

> *“'MKMapRectGetMaxX' has been replaced by property 'MKMapRect.maxX'”*

When I changed the syntax to

```
var corners =  [MKMapPoint(x: MKMapRect(MKMapRect.world).MaxX, y: MKMapRectGetMaxY(MKMapRect.world)),
```

I get this error message

> *“Cannot invoke initializer for type 'MKMapRect' with an argument list of type '(MKMapRect)'”*

How can I get this line of code to run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MKMapRect.world` is already an instance of `MKMapRect`; There is no need to wrap it in the `MKMapRect` initialiser.

You simply want

```
var corners =  [MKMapPoint(x: MKMapRect.world.MaxX, y: MKMapRect.world.maxY)]
```